# Alamofire unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

I use this Alamofire code to download images for URL

```
func getImage(imageUrlString: String, completionHandler: (responseObject: UIImage?, error: NSError?) -> ()) {
        makeGetImageCall(imageUrlString, completionHandler: completionHandler)
    }

    func makeGetImageCall(imageUrlString: String, completionHandler: (responseObject: UIImage?, error: NSError?) -> ()) {
        //Perform request
        print("Trying to get: " + imageUrlString)
        Alamofire.request(.GET, imageUrlString, headers: ["Authorization": NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().stringForKey("BasicAuthenticationString")!])
            .responseImage { request, response, result in
                print(request)
                print(response)
                print(result)
                completionHandler(responseObject: result.value, error: nil)
        }
    }
```

This is my class that uses the method:

```
public class NewsListEntry: NSObject {
    public var thumbnail: String = ""
    public var thumbnailImage: UIImage = UIImage()
    public var thumbnailDownloaded: Bool = false


    public func downloadThumbnail() {
        print(self.title)
        GetImageHandeler().getImage(self.thumbnail, completionHandler: { (responseObject, error) in
        })
    }
}
```

Then i get a:

```
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
```

What have i done wrong?

This is the errors im getting:

[image]

[image]

Comment: `NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().stringForKey("BasicAuthenticationString")!` is probably `nil`.

Comment: Added a print, it's not nil.

Comment: It works for like 6 image, then i get the error, and the URL is valid when i get the error.

Comment: This is the only part of your code where I see a forced-unwrapping, so it *has to be nil* to give this specific error message. Unless this error happens on another line of code that we don't see in this question? In this case please edit your question with all the relevant code and information.

Comment: I've added two screenshots for the error, i don't know how to see where in the code the error is happening?

Answer (score 1):

> What have i done wrong?

Two things. First, you are using the force-unwrap operator somewhere, possibly here:

```
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().stringForKey("BasicAuthenticationString")!
```

This means you're guaranteeing that the return value isn't `nil`, but in this case, it was. Since you broke your promise, the app crashes.

Second, ***PLEASE DO NOT STORE AUTHORIZATION STRINGS IN NSUSERDEFAULTS***. iOS has a highly secure keychain for a reason. `NSUserDefaults` provides no encryption. Please use the keychain. There are wrapper libraries like [Locksmith](https://github.com/matthewpalmer/Locksmith) and [SSKeychain](https://github.com/soffes/sskeychain) which can help you.

Comment: I added print for BasicAuthenticationString, it's never nil. So it must be something else, but i can't see that i'm using any other force-unwraps.

Comment: I've added two screenshots for the error, i don't know how to see where in the code the error is happening?

Comment: Set an exception breakpoint to see where the error occurs: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-breakpoint_navigator/articles/adding_an_exception_breakpoint.html

Comment: I get the same exc_breakpoint code=1 as in the screenshot provided, even with exception breakpoint.

Answer (score 1):

You are unwrapping the result without checking if it's valid or not. Add the following code:

```
Alamofire.request(.GET, imageUrlString, headers: ["Authorization": NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().stringForKey("BasicAuthenticationString")!])
    .responseImage { request, response, result in
        print(request)
        print(response)
        print(result)
        switch result {
        case .Success(let value):
            completionHandler(responseObject: value, error: nil)
        case .Failure(_, let error):
            completionHandler(responseObject: nil, error: error)
        }
}
```

If using Swift 2, you'll need to change the `error` parameter of the `completionHandler` block from `NSError?` to `ErrorType`.

Comment: @LordVermillion Maybe the `imageUrlString` is not valid. Can you post the log traces?

Comment: The string is valid, if i put it in my browser i get the Image.